# Template of Template c++

Tags: c++, templates

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    template <typename T>
    class DynamicArray
    {
        T *array;
        unsigned int elements;
        unsigned int size;


    public:
        void expand_array(int extra_size)
        {
            T *new_array= new T[size + extra_size];
            //copy integers from old array
            memcpy(new_array,array,elements*sizeof(T));
            //make 0 the integers from new part of the array
            memset(new_array + size, 0, extra_size * sizeof(T));
            delete [] array;
            array = new_array;
            size += extra_size;
        }
        //constructors
        DynamicArray()
        {
            array = new T[8];
            elements = 0;
            size = 8;
            memset(array,0,size*sizeof(T));
        }
        DynamicArray(const unsigned int  size)
        {
            array= new T[size];
        }
        virtual ~DynamicArray()
        {
            delete [] array;
        }
        void add(T new_element)
        {
            if(elements>=size)
                    expand_array(8);
            array[elements++] = new_element;
        }
        int get (const unsigned int index) const
        {
            if(index< elements)
                    return array[index];
            return -1;
        }
        void add(const unsigned int index, T new_element)
        {
            if(index>size)
                expand_array(index- size +1);
            array[index] = new_element;
            elements = index +1;

        }
        DynamicArray &operator=(DynamicArray &ab)
        {
            elements=ab.elements;
            size=ab.size;
            if (this == &ab)
                return *this;
            delete array;
            if(ab.array)
            {
                array= new T[size];
                memcpy(array,ab.array,elements*sizeof(T));
            }
            else
            {
                array=0;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        DynamicArray(const DynamicArray& source)
        {
            elements=ab.elements;
            size=ab.size;
            if(ab.array)
            {
                array= new T[size];
                memcpy(array,ab.array,elements*sizeof(T));
            }
            else
            {
                array=0;
            }
        }

    };



    int main()
    {
        DynamicArray<int> da(2);
        DynamicArray<int> db(2);

        DynamicArray< DynamicArray<int> > array_of_arrays(2);

        array_of_arrays[0] = da;/ 
        //array_of_arrays[1] = db;
        /*
        da[0]=5;
        da[1]=2;
        db[0]=3;
        db[1]=4;
        cout<<array_of_arrays[0][0]<<endl;
        */
        system("color 0C");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I need help in understanding why this gives me an error:

> error C2676: binary '[' : '`DynamicArray<T>`' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

i added this

```
          T& operator[](unsigned int index)//important to provide this operator
                {
                    if (index > size)
                     {
                            expand_array(index-size);
                    }
                    return array[index];
                }
```

but subequently i got invalid allocation size error during runtime.I try to try it and figure that the problem is somewhere about this area

```
                    if(ab.array)
            {
                array= new T[size];
                memcpy(array,ab.array,elements*sizeof(T));
            }
```

but i have no idea why is that so.
Any ideas?

Thanks I figured it out: One of the attributes are not initialise to a proper valuein one of the constructors
DynamicArray(const unsigned int  size)
.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me, `array_of_arrays(2)` is *not* an array, it's a `DynamicArray` which does not define the `[]` operator.

Comment: @Lightness: `[]` is a *binary* operator, although not really an *infix* operator, since the argument appears inside the brackets.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Great, but what is `[`?

Comment: @user1203499: A typical way to debug programs is to narrow down the problem. In this case, the issue has nothing to do with templates whatsoever, yet your question (and most notably its title) focus on templates almost exclusively. Please fix that.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you on your way, but your question makes less sense now. Also, please format your code!

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with templates. The problem is that you use the `[]` operator on `array_of_arrays`. However the `DynamicArray` class does not define `operator[]`.

What it does define is a method named `add`, so maybe you meant to call that instead? I.e. `array_of_arrays.add(0, da);` instead of `array_of_arrays[0] = da;`.

However it would probably be more idiomatic to simply define `operator[]` on your class.

Answer (score 0):

`DynamicArray` does not define a subscript operator.

This would typically look like:

```
T& operator[] (unsigned int index)
{
    if (index > size)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    return array[index];
}
```